# jQuery + <a> tag

Tags: php, jquery

I've created a Facebook/Twitter style status update where the new Status' get added to an unordered list. I now want to add a "REMOVE" function to it, however, I'm not sure how to best accomplish this.

1. In my list item, create my [a] tag with the unique ID of the status post ID and set a listener class
2. Have jQuery listen for [a] tags with the listener class
3. POST the ID over to the PHP script to remove the post; if successful return with "ok" or if failed return with "fail"
4. In the callback function, if it's OK, then find the element and remove it

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, was just wondering if there was a better, more efficient way to accomplish this

Comment: That seems like a perfectly sane approach. Is there a specific problem you're having with the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<li id="id-1234">
   Some text
   <a href="#" class="remove_li">Remove</a>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(){
    $('.remove_li').live('click', function(){
       var id = $(this).parent().attr('id').substring(3);
       var that = this;
       $.post('url.php', {id: id}, function(data, status){
           if(status == 'success'){
               $(that).parent().remove();
           } else {
               alert("Couldn't delete");
           }
       });
    });
}
```